# Can I reset the ChangeId in Cache Table for Change Notification

Tags: asp.net, caching, sqlcachedependency

What happens if I reset the changeId value in the table

```
AspNet_SqlCacheTablesForChangeNotification
```

One of the rows is currently maxed out at 2.x billion, and our updates are failing. I tried changing the type to BigInt but the application reading it is failing. I need to reset these to 0. Is that ok? Will there be problems?

Comment: do you know how/where the old valud of changeID is kept ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick answer is... yes.  We recently ran into this issue and had the same question.  A number of sites I've found had unanswered questions regarding this.  After much hunting, I had no choice but to just go for it.  Here is what I did, and it worked just fine.

There is an update being called by the trigger added to one or more of your tables.  Should look like this:

EXEC dbo.AspNet_SqlCacheUpdateChangeIdStoredProcedure N'YourTableName'

This stored procedure is not using an identity column, but a regular INT column and updated by 'changeId = changeId + 1'.  Once the MAX value is reached, it, well, blows up.  Change this UPDATE statement as follows:

Replace:

`SET changeId = changeId + 1`

With:

```
SET changeId =
    CASE
        WHEN changeId = 2147483647  --Max INT
        THEN 1
        ELSE changeId + 1
    END
```

It should look like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AspNet_SqlCacheUpdateChangeIdStoredProcedure] 
         @tableName NVARCHAR(450) 
     AS

     BEGIN 
         UPDATE dbo.AspNet_SqlCacheTablesForChangeNotification WITH (ROWLOCK) 
         SET changeId = 
            CASE 
                WHEN changeId = 2147483647 -- Max INT
                THEN 1
                ELSE changeId + 1 
            END
         WHERE tableName = @tableName
     END
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's funny - I no longer work for the company this was an issue for and the client has since dropped the contract with my former employer, but it's still good to know.

Comment: Glad it was useful.  I know it was frustrating for me not finding and answer, so hope this assists anyone that runs into it.